# Dexguard always crash with enum

Tags: android, dexguard

I'm using DexGuard Enterprise for my apps. And I find that whenever I use a library that have ENUM in it (for eg: ZXing), DexGuard did something to the code that my app would crash with errors like

```
java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:49)
at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211)
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:191)
at com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.valueOf(:24)
```

I tried options such as these (as I found them on other questions), but not working

```
-keep enum com.google.zxing.** {
    *;
}
```

what seems to be the problem? How could I fix it? It's bugging me for weeks now.

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/glass/proguard.cfg gives a list of things you can try. It didn't work for me :-(, still can't get zxing working with dexguard, but maybe it may spark an idea for what may be tried?

Comment: In my case, the error is more like `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find CaptureActivity. Make sure one of the zxing-android libraries are loaded.`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following in your proguard file.

```
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add  `allowoptimization` also

```
   -keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }
```

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#enumerations